# Is this the correct usage of the word cranial

Tags: register

My doubt is about using the word "cranial" here. Does this make sense?

> This is great. I am glad I was able to activate something **cranial** in you.

Comment: ***Cranial***: connected with the cranium
*cranial nerves/injuries* http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cranial -  I think you mean ***cerebral***: (formal) relating to the mind rather than the feelings: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cerebral?q=cerebral

Comment: Proof-reading is off-topic; and what research have you done?  Please refer to the [Help page](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: @TrevorD This isn't a request for proofreading. It's a request about word usage. *Cranium* means skull and is used figuratively to refer to the brain, as in *Use your cranium*.  The adjective is a poor fit for brain activity as Josh61 points out.

Comment: You don’t mean “your doubt” — you mean “your **question”**!

Comment: @deadrat I also asked "what research have you done?"

Comment: It is not incorrect.  It does represent a jocular manner of expression, however, and cannot be considered "formal".

Comment: @tchrist It was my edit that added "doubt". Should I have used "question" instead?

Answer (score 6):

**activate something cranial in you** is likely to be taken for mild or jocular sarcasm.

It's a more erudite way of saying, "I'm glad I was able to get that idea into your thick skull."